# React Native : 0.41 app.json

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the thing with the new app.json file generated in react native. I recently upgraded to 0.41.2 and found a new **app.json** file in my react project directory. Can someone help me figure out what this file is actually for ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's used for the new `react-native eject` command. As stated in the RN source code:

> The eject command re-creates the `android` and `ios` native folders. Because native code can be difficult to maintain, this new script allows an `app.json` to be defined for the project, which is used to configure the native app. The `app.json` config may contain the following keys:

- `name` - The short name used for the project, should be TitleCase
- `displayName` - The app's name on the home screen

Feel free to check the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/eject/eject.js#L16)

Comment: Thanks, and what is `jsconfig.json` file for?

Comment: is it safe to remove this file if I created my project through react native cli, without usig create-react-native-app thing?

Comment: i'd like to know too if it's safe to delete the file if i'm using react-native cli

Comment: link broken :(.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't plan to `eject` I removed the `app.json` File (just to have less files flying around at root level). App still works as expected.